# Should I control for categorical control variables that are related to my independent variable in panel with many panels, short time length?

Tags: panel-data, controlling-for-a-variable

I am doing a panel study where I have a sample of persons $i=1...N$ (up to $N=300$), that have some personality dimension quantified as variable $x$, over a time horizon $t=1...T$ (up to $T=20$). From this, I am trying to predict some other variable $y$ related to the person that is of economic interest, i.e. my regression model is

$y_{it}= \alpha + \beta x_{it} + c_{i} + \tau_t,$

where $c_i$ controls for individual (person) effects and $\tau_t$ for year effects (e.g. macroeconomic effects).

I want to find out in what way the variable $x$ related to the variable $y$ over time, in the sense of:

*"Managers that have an incremental increase of 1 unit in their variable $x$ (which we have derived and measured as to give a good indication of an important personality trait whose impact in managers we want to measure in this work) will lead to $\beta$ unit change in a firm's financial performance indicator $y$."*

Now, I am unsure regarding the exact usage of the control variable $c$. As these are individual person effects *beyond* the quantifyable, measurable $x$, there is no benefit from *estimating* these effects for each manager, as this would only happen ex-post and not serve any intended generalization of my results outside the sample.

However, clearly there are *good* and *bad* managers out there, that will necessitate the *control*.

But as my quantifyable "personality variable" $x$ is probably related to the person effects $c$ (and if it were not, it would be worthless as a measure the effect of a quantifyable personal attribute on the person's managing skills), I am afraid that the $c$ might eat up some effects that would otherwise be attibuted to the $x$, as in, "we measured a very low $x$ for this manager, and according to previous literature and our hypotheses, this should be correlated with his very bad firm performance $y$, but instead we find that there is no such significant correlation, but instead he is just a bad manager (low $c$)." But whether he is good or bad, is what we actually want to find out using the measured and quantified $x$, to predict future performance $y$ using $x$.

As there are very many managers ($N=300$) and time periods are at most $T=20$ years (average is much shorter), this means the model may tend to fit 300 $c_i$ instead of one $\beta$, indicating an effect that is much smaller than it should be. This indicates that I should not control for managers and leave the $c$ out of the above equation. Are there extra rules as to how to deal with this problem when we face such a short panel length and large number of panels (in addition, $T=20$ is only the maximum; they are on average $T=11$)?

Comment: As this question has now gone unanswered and uncommented for two days, can someone perhaps suggest the reason for this? I did my best formulating the question :)